# how to identify the unknown class in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

In the problem of multi-label classification how to identify the unknown class which is not in training labels or classes. In the prediction phase, the classifier puts the data in any of the class even though it's not related to any of the classes or labels?
For binary, the prediction probability of classification is 50/50 so how to interpret these as the confusion or just anomaly but when the data appears in both of the class or the similar to both of the class we can understand this scenario but what about the data which should be in any of the classes.
So, how to handle the same situation for multi-class or a general solution which can provide the proper classification for unknown and non-relevant data.

Comment: Your question is a bit convoluted. It is always nice to have an example to see what exactly you are taking about. As far as I understand you have labels for some classes but expect that there is some hidden class. Maybe try to model your data using clustering (e.g. K-means) so see if you are able to find any evidence for that.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close as too broad; it's hard to tell exactly what is being asked for but it seems like it's identification of confounding variables, which is far too wide a topic for a single post.

Answer (score 2):

I have come across a very similar problem lately. It is a case of novelty/anomaly detection as you have mentioned.

**There are broadly 2 "working" solutions to these type of problems:**

1. You can check the *softmax-posterior probability value* of the output layer for all classes and threshold it(say 0.5). If the probability is < 0.5 for all other classes, then definitely this test case is an outlier(our unknown class in this case).
2. Adding a *Garbage class* and training it. But, collecting/randomly generating the features for this unknown class may sometimes become tedious and difficult. It is dependent on the application and on the number of classes. If you have smaller number of classes(<10), then you could try this too.

Best would be to try both and see which one best fits the purpose of your application and which increases your prediction accuracy positively.